# Como dejar fijo el header y footer

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente código

```js
$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main(){
 $('.menu_bar').click(function(){
  if (contador == 1) {
   $('nav').animate({
    left:'0'
   });
   contador=0;
  }else{
   contador=1;
   $('nav').animate({
    left:'-100%'
   });
  }
 }); 
 //Mostramos y ocultamos submenus
 $('.submenu').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.children').slideToggle();
 });
}
```

```css
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer{
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 50px;
 position: fixed;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
} 

#logo h1{
 color: #85929E;
 font:bold 25px Verdana;
}

#logo{
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 text-align:left;
 width:80px;
}

#logo1{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 90px;
 margin-top:-75px;
 text-align:center;
 width:100px;
}

#logo2 p{
 color: #85929E;
 font:bold 20px Verdana;
 text-align: center;
}

#menu{
 float:center;
 text-align:center;
}

.container{
 text-align:center;
}

.menu_bar{
 display:none;
}

header{
 width: 100%;
}

header  nav {
 background:#023859;
 z-index:1000;
 max-width: 900px;
 width:95%;
 margin:20px auto;
 margin-left:150px;
}


header nav ul{
 list-style:none;
}

header nav ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

header nav ul li:hover{
 background: #85929E;
}

header nav ul li a{
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 20px;
}

header nav li a span{
 margin-right:10px;
}

header nav ul li:hover .children{
 display: block;
}

header nav ul li .children{
 display: none;
 background: #011826;
 position: absolute;
 width: 120%;
 z-index:1000;
}

header nav ul li .children li {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

header nav ul li .caret{
 position: relative;
 top: 3px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right:10px;
}

header nav ul li .children li a{
 display: block;
 
}

header nav ul li .children li  a span{
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 top:3px;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left:10px;
}

header nav ul li .caret{
position: relative;
top: 3px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
 body{
  padding-top:80px;
 }
 #logo{
  display:none;
 }
 #logo1{
  display: none;
 }
 .menu_bar{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  /*background:#E6344A;*/
  color:  #85929E;
 }
 .menu_bar .bt-menu{
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  color: #85929E;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
 }
 
 .menu_bar span{
  float:right;
  font-size: 40px;
 }
 
 header nav {
  width: 80%;
  height: calc(100%-80px);
  position:fixed;
  right:100%;
  margin:0;
  overflow:scroll;
 }
 
 header nav ul li{
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 }
 header nav ul li a{
  display: block;
 }
 header nav ul li:hover .children{
  display:none;
 }
 header nav ul li .children{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;

 }
 header nav ul li .children li a{
  margin-left:20px;
 }
 header nav ul li .caret{
  float:right;
 }
 #contenedor{
 width:80%;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:30px;
}
#contenedor h1{
 font-size:24px;
 font:bold 25px Verdana;
}
form{
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
#contenedor form{
 margin-top:20px;
}
#form {
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
}
input[type="text"], [type="date"]{
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 height:35px;
 font-size: 16px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
select{
 margin-top: 20px;
 width:60%;
 padding-left:5px;
 height:35px;
 font-size: 16px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
#contenedor .input-50{
 width: 48%;
}
#contenedor .input-100{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="menu_bar">
   <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span>Control PAC</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="logo">
    <h1>Control<br/>PAC</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="menu">
    <nav>
     <ul>
      <li class="<?php echo $pagina == 'inicio' ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="?p=inicio"><span class="icon-home"></span>Inicio</a>
      <li class="submenu">
       <a href="#"><span class="icon-user-plus"></span>Registar<span class="caret icon-circle-down"></span></a>
       <ul class="children">
        <li class="<?php echo $pagina == 'reg-conductor' ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="?p=reg-conductor">Conductor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Propietario</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
       <li><a href="#">Modificar</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Retirar</a></li>
      </ul>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
   <div id="logo1">
    <img src="imagenes/logo-ConectarTV.png">
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
  <div id="contenedor">
   <h1 id="titulo-form"> Registrar conductor</h2>
   <div id="form">
    <form>
     <input class="input-100" type="text" id="cedula" placeholder="Ingrese la cedula del conductor">
     <input class="input-50" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del conductor">
     <input class="input-50" type="text" id="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese el apellido del conductor"> 
     <select class="input-50" type = "text" id="dpto" placeholder = "Escoga un departamento">
     </select> 
     <select class="input-50" type = "text" id="cdd" placeholder = "Escoga una ciudad"> 
     <input class="input-100" type="text" id="tel" placeholder="Ingrese el telefono del conductor" class="">
     <select class="input-100" type = "text" id="lic">
      <option value="0">Escoga una categoria de licencia</option>
      <option value="A1">A1-Motocicletas hasta 125 c.c de cilindrada</option>
      <option value="A2">A2-Motocicletas, motociclos y motiriclicos de más de 125 c.c de cilindrada</option>
      <option value="B1">B1-Automoviles, camperos, camionetas y microbuses de servicio particular</option>
      <option value="B2">B2-Camiones, rígidos,buesetas y buses para servicio particular</option>
      <option value="B3">B3-Vehículos articulados de servicio particular</option>
      <option value="C1">C1-Automoviles, camperos, camionetas y microbuses de servicio publico</option>
      <option value="C2">C2-Camiones, rígidos,buesetas y buses para servicio publico</option>
      <option value="C3">C3-Vehículos articulados de servicio publico</option>
     </select> 
     <input class="input-50" type="date">
     <input class="input-50" type="text" id="nrolic" placeholder="Numero de licencia del conductor" class="">
     <select class="input-50" type = "text" id="tpveh">
      <option value="0">Escoga un tipo de vehiculo</option>
      <option value="camion">Camion</option>
      <option value="camioneta">Camioneta</option>
      <option value="carry">Carry</option>
      <option value="moto">Moto</option>
     </select> 
     <select class="input-50" type = "text" id="plcs">
       <option value="0">Escoga una placa</option>
     </select> 
     <input type = "button" value = " Registrar" class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar"/>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>  
    
    <footer>
    <section id="logo2">
     <p id="pie">Desarrollado por NABUX INC<br/>
     <span class="icon-whatsapp"></span>3105361395</p>
    </section>
   </footer>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Si le hago scroll al formulario lo que queda debajo del footer lo tapa y no le puedo hacer mas scroll para llegar al botón para enviar el formulario, lo que me gustaría es que solo se vea el efecto del movimiento en el formulario y pueda bajar hasta el final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solo tienes que haces dos cambios.

1._ La propiedad padding-bottom para que tenga un espacio entre el contenedor y el final del documento.

```
#contenedor {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 80px;}
```

2._ la propiedad para que flote y no se quede fijo el footer el postion:fixed;

```
footer {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 50px;
 position: fixed;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;}
```

Espero que sea de ayuda, Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de mucha ayuda. Ya logre lo que quería

Answer (score 0):

Dado que el footer está posicionado como `absolute`, se va a colocar de forma absoluta al pie de la página. Una forma de evitar este comportamiento sería agregarle un padding al contenedor de principal (el que contiene el formulario) para que el footer se coloque encima del padding, y no del contenido.